# Elasticsearch watcher "watcher.actions.email.html.sanitization" table attributes

Tags: elasticsearch, html-email, html-sanitizing, elasticsearch-watcher

I construct email alerts in **elasticsearch watcher** using HTML and I have also configured to sanitize following html tags in `elasticsearch.yml`

```
watcher.actions.email.html.sanitization:
  allow: _tables, _blocks, _formatting, _links, _styles
```

But in my alerts, I see the table is constructed but the table attributes were not considered while constructing the table. For example, the border, cellpadding and colspan were never applied on my table. Table example given below

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='5' style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px'><thead><tr><th>Type</th><th colspan='5'>Version</th></tr></thead><tbody> etc.
```

I can still achieve it by completely disabling the HTML sanitization like below, but it was not recommended as it involved security risks.

```
watcher.actions.email.html.sanitization.enabled: false
```

I have even tried to use `allow: _tables:all`, but it didn't work and it doesn't seem to be the right thing.

Is there a way to achieve it by enabling only few tags along with it's attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion from [elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/watcher-watcher-actions-email-html-sanitization-table-attributes/50971/2)

Right now `border` and `cellpadding` attributes are always dropped. You can get the `style` attribute working by allowing `_styles` in the sanitizer config.